# JSF dynamic javascript escape quotes

Tags: javascript, jsf, escaping

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="myPrintFunction(#{myValue})">
Print</a>
```

This works fine unless myValue contains an apostrophe.

How do I work around this?

Comment: Escape it in a method of your backing bean: `#{myBean.getMyValueEscaped()}`    `public String getMyValueEscaped() { return myValue.replace("'", "\\'"); }`

Comment: Rather keep this out of the bean logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JSF utility library OmniFaces already, then you can also just use its of:escapeJS() function:

```
<html ... xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">

'#{of:escapeJS(_selectedItem.item.webName)}'
```